# Issue plotting a time table with filled slots

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I've got a boardroom booking system where a person books a boardroom and the booking is visible on the web for employees in the company. Currently, it plots correctly if there is one booking for the day.

There are several boardrooms, and any of these can be booked anytime between 8:00 and 17:00.

If there is one boardroom booking, it looks like this:

[image]

But when there is another boardroom booking, on the same day, it looks like this:

[image]

My for loops to create the grid looks like this:

```
for($h = 8; $h < 17; $h++) { // hours
    for($m = 0; $m < 4; $m++) { // 15 minutes
        echo '<tr><td>' . $h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0") . '</td>'; //plots the timeslot
        foreach($boardrooms as $boardroom) { // array of boardrooms
            foreach($boardroomBookings as $booking) { // array of boardroom bookings
                if(date('H:i',strtotime($h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0"))) >= date('H:i',strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['start_time'])) &&
                date('H:i',strtotime($h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0"))) < date('H:i',strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['end_time'])) &&
                $boardroom['Boardroom']['name'] == $booking['Boardroom']['name']) {
                    echo '<td rowspan="0" style="background-color:#8cc63f; border-bottom:none">' . $this->Html->link($booking['BoardroomBooking']['name'], array('action' => 'view', $booking['BoardroomBooking']['id'])) . '</td>'; // writes the name into the timeslot
                } else {
                    echo '<td></td>'; // writes an empty block
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>'; // closes the row
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is the watered down arrays (only showing data that is used);

```
$boardrooms = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Pretoria)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Small Boardroom (Pretoria)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Medium Boardroom (No Screen) (Pretoria)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Floor 3) (Pretoria)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Durban)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Cape Town)'
        )
    )
)

$boardroomBookings = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'BoardroomBooking' => array(
            'id' => '1206',
            'name' => 'asdfasdf',
            'boardroom_id' => '1',
            'date' => '2013-05-21',
            'start_time' => '08:15:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00:00'
        ),
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Pretoria)'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'BoardroomBooking' => array(
            'id' => '1208',
            'name' => 'Test 2',
            'boardroom_id' => '4',
            'date' => '2013-05-21',
            'start_time' => '09:00:00',
            'end_time' => '12:00:00'
        ),
        'Boardroom' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'name' => 'Big Boardroom (Floor 3) (Pretoria)'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Would you mind providing an array with example data? I would have a look on it then.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat I've added the arrays for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it.

I figured it's probably because of the $boardroomBookings loop and the comparison between the booked boardroom and the loop boardroom, so I used some fine tweaking to get it to work.

```
for($h = 8; $h < 17; $h++) {
    for($m = 0; $m < 4; $m++) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0") . '</td>';
        foreach($boardrooms as $boardroom) {
            foreach($boardroomBookings as $booking) {
                if(date('H:i',strtotime($h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0"))) >= date('H:i',strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['start_time'])) &&
                date('H:i',strtotime($h . ':' . str_pad(($m*15),2,"0"))) < date('H:i',strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['end_time'])) &&
                $boardroom['Boardroom']['name'] == $booking['Boardroom']['name']) {
                    $writerow = true;
                    $rowspan = (strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['end_time']) - strtotime($booking['BoardroomBooking']['start_time']))/900;
                    echo '<td style="background-color:#8cc63f; border-bottom:none">' . $this->Html->link($booking['BoardroomBooking']['name'], array('action' => 'view', $booking['BoardroomBooking']['id'])) . '</td>';
                    break;
                } else {
                    $writerow = false;
                }
            }
            if(!$writerow) {
                echo '<td></td>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```